# setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB.UTF8') not working on windows

Tags: php, windows, utf-8, setlocale

Why does `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB.UTF8');` return false on Windows Server 2003 R2 - Zend CE PHP 5.3.5 ?

Function in question: [`setlocale`](http://php.net/setlocale).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the PHP Manual:

> The return value of `setlocale()` depends on the system that PHP is running. It returns exactly what the system **setlocale** function returns.

So in your case it returns false because the system returns false. It is likely that the locale you're using is not available on your system.

A list of `setlocale` strings supported by Windows is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf(v=vs.100).aspx). For British English you want `eng`, `english-uk`, or `uk`. Windows doesn't support multi-byte character sets like UTF-8 though; you will probably end up with Windows-1252.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need to change the system locale?

Comment: OK, so for some reason XML files which are UTF-8 encoded processed via XMLReader, XPath fwrite ending up to be not UTF-8 encoded on output, characters getting messed up for some reason, thanks.

Comment: The system locale is almost certainly nothing to do with your issue. Put the code you are having trouble with in your question.

Comment: Unfortunetly its to complex - frameworks based but what it do its taking UTF-8 XML on input and write it to other file with not modifiying anything but characters getting messed up anyway.

Comment: It's impossible to determine what the problem could be without a small test case that demonstrates the problem, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that the problem of Windows not supporting utf-8 can be improved with something like this:

```
$str=strftime('%a'); //for example
if(!mb_check_encoding($str,'utf-8')) $str=utf8_encode($str);
```