# setlocal, strftime - Windows and lowercase issues

Tags: php, strftime, setlocale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [setlocale(LC_ALL, ‘en_GB.UTF8’) not working on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489339/setlocalelc-all-en-gb-utf8-not-working-on-windows)

I have the following PHP code:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fi_FI");
echo strftime(" in Finnish is %A, %B %d, %G at %l:%M%p");
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_CA");
echo strftime(" in French Canadian is %A, %B %d, %G at %l:%M%p");
```

Problems:

1. On my Windows machine, it displays as English. How do I configure PHP or Windows to make this work right?
2. On my Linux machine, it displays this:

   - in Finnish is maanantai, lokakuu 15, 2012 at 6:42
   - in French Canadian is lundi, octobre 15, 2012 at 6:42

Any ideas why the words are in lower case?

Answer (score 2):

On your windows machine, the locale names you are setting might not be available.
According to the documentation on **[setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)**, the valid locale strings, are available at [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Your strings, for windows would be

> French Canadian: "frc" or "french-canadian"
>
> Finnish: "fin" or "finnish"
>
> The three-letter language-string codes are valid in Windows
> 2000 and later operating systems.

The months etc are all lower case because:
The French and Finnish don't use capital letters for for days of the week and months.
(**[Finnish](http://www.uta.fi/%7Ekm56049/finnish/month.html)**)
(**[French](http://french.languagedaily.com/wordsandphrases/french-months)**)

Comment: oh ... if that's the case, then this output is correct. I just assumed it was supposed to be capitalized. Any ideas why it displays in English on my Windows machine?

Comment: It shouldn't exhibit different behaviour. The locale string might not be working under windows. Check the [language string reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)