# How to get numeric float (not string!) when json_encoding?

Tags: php, number-formatting

I need to have a numeric float using a dot separator, that stays a numeric after (json) encoding for sending in the POST headers to a third-party API.

However, have been trying for a few hours, but cannot get it to work.

What I need is:

```
{
    "price": 17.95,
    // BUT NOT:
    "price": "17.95" OR 17,95
}
```

**Why?** Because the receiving API endpoint does a check for the first but throws a `non-numeric` error on the latter 2 values.

Now, we're in Holland. So our "locale" uses a comma separator. Working around that by setting the locale from `nl_NL` to `en_US` gives the `number_format` function the correct format, however, as a string.

Casting a comma or dot separated string using `(float)` causes it to lose any value from the point of separation. (`"17.95"` becomes `17`)

Updating the product details is a function taking a few arguments that passes them on without modification to cURL. Which encodes the array of POST variables into what it should be above. I'm limited in passing the following:

```
$client->updateShopItem($shopId, $articleNumber, $updateArray)
```

`$shopId` = int
`$articleNumber` = string
`$updateArray` = array

Complete, correct, call looks like:

```
$client->updateShopItem(12345, "a1b2c3", [
    "price" => 17.95,
    "sale_price" => 12.99,
    //... other values
]);
```

Values to use instead of the ones in example above are string type: "17,95".

Have tried:

```
$price = "17,95" //Starting point (locale = nl_NL)

number_format($price, 2) // "17.00" - incorrect type and value
number_format(str_replace(',', '.', $price), 2) // "17.95" - string
(float) str_replace(',', '.', $price); // 17,95 - comma
(float) number_format(str_replace(',', '.', $price), 2) //17,95 - comma

setLocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US'); //Changing locale here, US uses dot separator

$check = locale_get_default(); // "en_US"

number_format($price, 2) // "17.00" - incorrect type and value
number_format(str_replace(',', '.', $price), 2) // "17.95" - string
(float) number_format(str_replace(',', '.', $price), 2) // 17,95 - comma
(float) str_replace(',', '.', $price); // 17,95 (can't figure why comma with US locale)
```

Extra test to see what `json_encode()` makes of the different types/values:

```
json_encode(["test1" => "17,95", "test2" => 17.95]);

//Results in: 
{"test1":"17,95","test2":17.95}
```

**UPDATE: to avoid confusion:** full code, only removed non-relevant stuff, otherwise unedited. Has included locale se

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'nl-NL');
$update = [
    'price'             => ((float)number_format(str_replace(',', '.', $prijs), 2)),
    'discount_price'    => (float) str_replace(',', '.', $actieprijs),
];

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'en-US');
// Update a shopitem
$update2 = [
    'price'             => ((float)number_format(str_replace(',', '.', $prijs), 2)),
    'discount_price'    => (float) str_replace(',', '.', $actieprijs),
];
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2: SOLUTION FOUND**
After some comments back 'n' forth with @KevinStich about his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40867300/1155833) found that the problem when trying to change the locale was in the fact that I'm on Windows.

His answer solves it, after adding the following code above where it needs to get set:

```
if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')) { //Works on "normal" server/Linux stuff
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'us'); //Windows is special
}
```

Found [in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) that the `setlocale()` function returns `false` if it didn't set a new locale, or else returns the new locale. Which led to the above and that @KevinStich's answer worked.

Comment: You can just type cast to float `(float)` before `number_format`.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, please see 3rd examples before/after locale setting. It replaces the dot with a comma. Difference with 2nd example is the `(float)` cast.

Comment: What is $client? Is this some class you can change? If this client works with your locale settings, it might always change this to use comma as seperator, which results in a string. And by the way: number_format always returns a string.

Comment: Hi @Seb. `$client` is Wienkit's [BeslistShopItemClient](https://github.com/wienkit/beslist-shopitem-api-php-client). I've debugged through the functions until where the call is made, the array (`$updateArray`) does not get touched or modified before `json_encode` by the cURL library. Which results in the last example (extra `json_encode()` test).

Comment: Have you tried setting locale to en_US before initializing the client, and reset it after the call?

Comment: Bad wording on my part. I mean cast to float the `$price` itself, not the results of number format.

Comment: @Seb Yes I have, tried some more variations based on [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40867300/1155833) from Kevin. No solution as of yet though.

Comment: @Andrew doing `(float) $price` where `$price = "17,95"` results in: `17`.

Comment: You can also use a cascading locale to find out which is the preferred locale on the current system. `$locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL', 'nl');` or `$locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8', 'en_US', 'us', 'en');` and see which one was set `echo $locale;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Nukeface's issue was related to the locale setting and different variables passed to [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) based on platform; specifically that Windows uses different locale names from unix systems.

setlocale's return value can help you diagnose if the call worked at all, and you can use [`localeconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php) to see some of your current locale settings.

It's likely you want to only do this specific to `json_encode()`'d information, so consider wrapping a setlocale to the right locale, the encode, and a setlocale back to your standard in its own function.

Here are the old answers that led to the discussion in the comments:

---

It looks like there's something odd going on with the scoping of your cast. I've seen this issue before and am not sure what to chalk it up to, I solved it with more parenthesis.

This worked for me in the REPL

```
var_dump(
    ((float)number_format(str_replace(',', '.', $price), 2))
);
float(17.95)
```

---

To make sure it's not a json_encode issue:

```
$price = "17,95";
$a = array();
$a[] = $price;
$a[] = ((float)number_format(str_replace(',', '.', $price), 2));

echo json_encode($a); // Prints ["17,95",17.95]
```

Comment: Just been mucking around with your answer, but when I copy you second `$a[]` (with the float), I get: `17,95` (not a string, but with a comma)

Comment: Try passing your desired separators in to number_format as follows:

`$a[] = ((float)number_format(str_replace(',', '.', $price), 2, '.', ','));`

Comment: If this doesn't work, there's likely some forced conversion for your number formats with the locale settings.

Try setting your LC_NUMERIC locale to 'en_US.utf8' before using json_encode. You may want to switch it back to the default after encoding to maintain state. You can verify your delimiter at this stage using [`localeconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php)'s entry for `decimal_point`

Comment: Have just tried: `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')` and `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US.utf8)`. These were followed immediately (next line of code) by your suggestion. Both return: `17,95`. Checking `localeconv()` both times it showed: `decimal_point => ','` (comma). Any suggestion as to what might cause this? Would most likely be on our live server for this project as well, so important to have that figured out.

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909911/php-setlocale-has-no-effect They are going the oposite way but it might be helpful to figure out, if any of the given ideas work. At least it looks like your setlocale is not working.

Comment: What is the return value of your LC_NUMERIC setlocale call?

Comment: @KevinStich *fist-bump* That was it! Some quick searching, it's Windows that's the problem when trying to change the locale (found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995953/php-setlocale-in-windows-7) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489339/setlocalelc-all-en-gb-utf8-not-working-on-windows). Found Windows supported characters [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf(v=vs.100).aspx). `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'us')` actually sets to US English (instead of `en_US`). I'll update question with answer+ref to your comment here!

Comment: Great to hear! I'll update my answer shortly with info from these comments. You should consider setting up a new function to set your locales to and from the US around your json_encode calls.